# Vue Sync Data on v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, v-for

inside my template I have this element:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="item in items">{{item.name}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

in my script I have:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data: () => ({ items: null }),
    mounted: function () {
        var vm = this;
        axios.get('/items')
         .then(function (response) {
          vm.items = response.data;
        });
   }
}
```

My question is how to do I get `<span>` elements show up and for the `v-for` execute once the response returned with a list of `items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `spans` created by `v-for` in a single root `div`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="item in items">{{item.name}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

And also there seems to be a problem with `vm.items = response;` which should be `vm.items = response.data;`, See [axios response schema](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) for more detail.

Comment: I edited my post, and with the suggestion I still can't get it to work

Comment: Maybe `console.log(response.data)` in `axios.get.then(...)` to see if the api returns what you expect.

Comment: Issue was my response was a JSON object and by making `response.data` an array list of `items` objects got it working :D